# Remove value from name-value pair string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript string like `dog=1,cat=2,horse=3`. The names and values can be anything. I want to remove dog and whatever value is associated with it from the string. So in this example I would end up with `cat=2,horse=3`. There may not be a entry for dog in the string, and it could be anywhere within the string, e.g. `cat=22,dog=17,horse=3` which would end up as `cat=22,horse=3`.

The names and values will just be alphanumeric with no special characters like quotes and equals signs within them.

What is the best way of going about this in JavaScript?

Comment: Use JSON, use a real JSON parser, and use real parsed objects. Don't make up your own serialization.

Comment: If above comment is not ok you could always split the string by ',' and work with the resulting array.

Comment: If the names and values can be anything, including commas and equals-signs, your question cannot be answered unless you provide more details on how they would be escaped.

Comment: @tucuxi I have updated the question to make this clear

Comment: Uhm anybody else thinking `string.replace("dog=1", "").replace(",,", ",")`? (The second replace is to avoid any duplicate `,`)

Comment: @somethinghere: Rather `.replace(/(,|^)dog=[^,]*/, ",")`

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, I only noticed later that they want to replace any value, so regex is the right one here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest solution:

```
str.split(",").filter(function(kv) {
    return kv.slice(0, 4) != "dog=";
}.join(",")
```

You can do some regex magic as well, but that's not going to be as clear (and maintainable):

```
str.replace(.replace(/(,|^)dog=[^,]*/g, "").replace(/^,/,"")
```

Comment: Nice. Regexes are harder to get right than split-filter-join

Answer (score 1):

You could do this, although may not be the best way:

1. convert the string to array as it is comma seperated.
2. remove the dog from the array.
3. join the array back as a string.